# Why Google search console shows wrong SERP position for keywords and pages?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing

google search console data shows lots of 1st positions for example but when I check it really in google SERP by my self manually, I see its wrong. Can anyone know what is the reason and how I can solve it? 
Thanks

Comment: May I know where you are looking in Search Console for keyword ranking positions?

Comment: Many different ways, mostly this way:
google new search console > performance > pages > click on target page > then check queries ranked for this specific page > apply position filter to check all pisitions 

second way :
google new search console > performance > queries > apply position filter on the column

Comment: The one you're checking, it is an average position that is shown. If you want simplified data, you can hover over the graph to see what positions it was shown for.

Comment: I applied 7 days period filter, but there is no exact data,
i have lots of keyword with rank 1st, but there nothing in first page even second page!

Answer (score 4):

The search console reports show the average position for when your page appears in the search results.  What is likely happening is that sometimes you are appearing first and sometimes you are not appearing at all.   Your average for when you do appear is what you are seeing in the 1st position.

When that happens to your site it is usually because Google is "tasting" your URLs.  It is experimenting with occasionally ranking them and seeing whether users have interest in them.  Google does this all the time, especially with new sites.

Comment: interesting concept of "tasting".  I wasn't aware they did this, but it makes perfect sense.  That explains some of the wild fluctuations I sometimes see.

Comment: There can be other reasons. Personalisation might make it show up for specifically people or when peoples search history favours your site. Localisation may make it show up to people in a specific place.